# PHP Date Function Seven days previous

Tags: php, date

I am trying to use PHP's Date Function to get the date of 7 days earlier in YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
date('Y-m-d');
```

when i try

```
date('Y-m-d-7');
```

i get an error

Comment: use `date('Y-m-d', strtodate('-7 days'))`

Comment: @Gavin Call to undefined function strtodate()

Comment: The function is [`strtotime`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Apologies, well spotted, `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'))`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use the `strtotime` method provided by PHP.

`date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'))`

Thanks to @lonesomeday for pointing out my mistake in the comments ;)

Comment: How do you get it with the hours minutes and seconds too... I can't get that to work with 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Comment: hey @Matthew - the following worked fine for me `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days'));` returning `2017-01-02 08:37:51` - what were you getting?

Comment: Gavin, thank you, I got it working. I don't know what I was doing wrong, I can't even remember. I appreciate you confirming it. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

With this, as with all PHP date stuff, it's nicer to use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
$date = new DateTime('7 days ago');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: is there any way i dont do it in one line ? since i am inserting it in a query

Comment: So in what query you are inserting it ? SQL?

Comment: @HarshaMV If you *must* do it in one line, use Gavin's answer. I doubt you really need to, however.

Comment: @Harsha M V you can do it in one line : echo (new DateTime('7 days ago'))->format('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-7 days'))
```

Or

```
date("Y-m-d", time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```