# Setting a date to current using DateTime and modifying it

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to 1) set a variable to the current date 2) format it as Y-m-d and 3) modify it to find a date 7 days in the past.

Here is the code I'm using to do this:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // get current date
$date->format('Y-m-d'); // format it 
$wow_date = $date->modify('-7 days'); // find 7 days before current date
```

When I run this I get a 500 error code and haven't been able to troubleshoot why this is happening. Would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

UPDATE

Thanks for the help / comments. Here is what I've ended up going with:

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); // get current date
$m_date = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // set it in format I need for queries
$wow_date = $date->modify('-7 days'); // get 7 days before
$m_wow_date = $wow_date->format('Y-m-d'); // format earlier date
```

Comment: You don't format anything. The output of the format call is thrown away.

Comment: http 500 will **not** being triggered by this code. The code is ok and should work

Comment: @Sven - I'm unclear why. Can you elaborate?

Comment: As stated in the documentation, a call to the `format` method returns a formatted string of the date that is stored inside the object. It does NOT store that format for later use.

Comment: I case you didn't know: The documentation is here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: @john k, as I said, the could will work. No HTTP 500 will be triggered. Definitely

Comment: 500 code should be trigged from other part of code wich use the result of $wow_date.. but with return false the rest of code returns 500. try configuring date_default_timezone_set as i say in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798228/php-date-function-seven-days-previous) SO thread:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
```

Or with DateTime class:

```
$date = new DateTime('7 days ago');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use the DateTime class but can't figure out why this approach isn't working.

Comment: Edited with a DateTime version.

Comment: And I do recommend that you set the default timezone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use object oriented style, try this

```
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
```

This is from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

Answer (score 0):

If your final goal is a variable of type String containing the formatted date a week ago, then you can do it all in one line:-

```
$formattedDate = (new \DateTime())->modify('-7 days')->format('Y-m-d');
echo $formattedDate;
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/8bgCk)

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure default timezone for your application.

Try to find it on your php.ini uncomment or add this lines:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Or via php script before use DateTime Class:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Find your desired timezone at [PHP MANUAL](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)

Comment: Remember to restart apache if you make chances on php.ini

Comment: @hek2mgl I dont understand your comment. The reference to manual is to help john k find timezone name for his location. If this config dont solve the problem, please post error output.

Comment: It is not a timezone problem.

Comment: Maybe his dont have this config set already. And the following code needs this date from $wow_date var. And this code output http 500 error