# PHP Show next 7 Days range

Tags: php, wordpress, api, date, range

I saw this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798228/php-date-function-seven-days-previous#_=_) to a thread and it works but doesn't create a range between the current day and seven days time. Which is what I need. Can anyone give me a hand please?

Update:
An easier way to word it. I want to Select data between two dates. For example current day and seven days time.

My current code:

```
if($current_day) {
            $data['current_day']=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));
```

Comment: What your 'range' means? can you write some example output of $data['current_day'] (which should be correct for you) ?

Comment: The code hooks into an API. I want it to pull down the next seven days of releases and display them in a widget on Wordpress. Currently the code (That is live) only displays the current day so it's:

 if($current_day) {
            $data['current_day']=date('Y-m-d');

By changing it too:
if($current_day) {
            $data['current_day']=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));

It covers only the releases due out in seven days time. Not a range between Today and seven days time

Comment: It look's like to me, you have to change some more. As @MateuszPalichleb sad, it is importend what $data['current_day'] should look like. Maybe the API only handle one date, not a range!?

Comment: The  API Does work with ranges. It's just trying to work out how. The official site does it - https://www.igdb.com/games/coming_soon

Comment: @sebkrueger Is this an easier way to word it? I want to  Select data between two dates. For example current day and seven days time.

Comment: I'am sure I got, what you mean with date/time range, but not sure if the API will support this feature. The Page you linked, show an website, that maybe change something in the "out-of-the-box" API, to get the results. The Key is, to find out, how dateranges should format for the API, the PHP side should be easy then.

Comment: No I don't want the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime('2011-05-11 12:00:00');

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

echo $interval->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

You can use this code sample if you have php 5.3 or above,

Else try to calculate the difference of two dates in seconds using `time()` and `strtotime()`. Then translate those seconds into days/hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: @eddie-stubbington, I think you have a specific release date which should fetched from database for example, to be used in difference calculation.

Comment: So it can't do ranges at all? The API's website features a range on this page - https://www.igdb.com/games/coming_soon

Comment: do you want a response like this? **7 days remains**

Comment: Not sure what 7 Days Remains means but I can try and see if that works/

Comment: this short code prints something like this: **2 days, 5 hours, 2 minutes, 5 seconds** which is time interval until the specific release date.

Comment: Oh a see. A countdown kinda thing. No not at the moment.

Comment: still I don't know whats a range mean? can you give me an example here? not in an external link

Comment: I don't want the time. 

I want anything that is released in between today and 7 days time to be displayed.

Comment: You should use a query to select appropriate records from your database, do you use MySQL?